# How to add YouTube embed (iframe) inside of divbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, embedding

How would I be able to add a YouTube embedded iframe inside of a Divbox using a text inputfield, button to submit and javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: What is a "divbox"? Where is your attempt?

Comment: Hi, please refer to this guide for a better question writing.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Always remember to put a code sample, and the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

By taking "Divbox" to mean "div" I have made an attempt at an answer:
You could do the following if the user knows the video ID (the string of characters at the end of a youtube url):

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function(d) {
  var full = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + document.getElementById("inp").value + '" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
  document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML = full;
}
```

```html
<button id="b">Go!</button>
<input id="inp" value="MPZI2M1fDi8"/>
<div id="frame"></div>
```